# Complicated DELETE

Tags: mysql

I want to delete some rows in a table. However the delete condition is not direct.This is just 1 table CUSTOMER:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    CUST_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRODUCT_CODE varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    USER_NAME varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2455046 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is what works for me:

```
select cust_id from CUSTOMER where user_name = '20012';
```

Then use the resulting cust_id in the following DELETE ($cust_id is result of query 1)

```
delete from CUSTOMER where cust_id = $cust_id
```

Note: This can only delete one user_name . Also I want to do this in 1 query, not 2.

```
  CUSTOMER t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      cust_id id
    FROM
      CUSTOMER
    where
      user_name IN ('20012', '20013', '20014')
  ) t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.id
```

The above apparently did not work.

Comment: `did not work` what does this mean?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) And you should provide table structures as wel `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE customer ( CUST_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRODUCT_CODE varchar(50) NOT NULL, USER_NAME varchar(150) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID), ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2455046 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , the above query is missing the DELETE FROM word, however I can't edit the original post. If I use this I deletes the entire TABLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unnecessarily complicating the logic. Instead of first getting all the customer id(s), for the given user_name values, you could simply filter on the user_name values. It is simply this:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE user_name IN ('20012', '20013', '20014')
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use this. I have to use 'cust_id' as the cascade delete will work only when you I use 'cust_id'. Basically I have to DELETE using only 'cust_id', even though I get user_name as input parameter.

Comment: @user1588766 who told you that cascade delete will not work in this case ! As long as a row is getting deleted, it will trigger cascade delete if there are referenced keys defined accordingly. Give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately cascade delete is setup only with 'cust_id' and not 'user_name'.

Comment: *"Unfortunately cascade delete is setup only with 'cust_id' and not 'user_name'."* Pretty sure you guys talk past one and other... @user1588766 See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) And you should provide table structures as wel `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question.

Comment: @user1588766 the cascade delete will work, even if you don't select by cust_id.  really.  try it.

Comment: I tried and it did not work. Basically cust_id is a foreign key in TABLE2. user_name is available only in CUSTOMER table. So I have to use cust_id reference to delete. This works: The only way it works so far : select cust_id from CUSTOMER where user_name = '20012'; delete from CUSTOMER where cust_id = $cust_id ($cust_id is result of query 1)  . However I need to pass multiple user_name in one query.

Comment: if it did not work, you were doing something else wrong.  cascade deletes do not depend on what where condition you use.  the delete in this answer will work.

Comment: @user1588766 as ysth said, the query in the answer should work without the cascade stopping things. Where you have your current `SELECT cust_id...; DELETE FROM...;` queries, what happens if you change it to `DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE user_name = '20012';` i.e. replace those two queries with just one?